# Can I send the RequestToken to the web browser or should I store it in database?

Tags: java, twitter, scribe

I use Scribe with Twitter API.

I do not know wether the `RequestToken` should remain invisible for the user or not. As it contains a field named `secret`, I thought that it was good to store it in database and only give the RequestToken's ID to the user as shown below :

[image: Twitter authentication flow]

**Question** : Do I really need to protect the RequestToken like this or can I expose it to the user (and re-send it in clear with the Verifier)?

Note : my server is stateless so I cannot store anything in a session.